# Prevent my PHP website from opening up on Internet explorer Browser

Tags: php, codeigniter, internet-explorer

There are a few jquery plugins and HTML5 on my website which have trouble running on Internet Explorer browser. If they dont work it will affect the functionality of my website. How do i disable my website from opening if a user opens my website through IE browser?
Something like display a message for the user saying "The website is not supported on this browser"

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Check output of following variable to check for the user agent

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check user-agent.
Using strpos

```
<?php
$browser =  'MSIE'; 
$user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
if(strpos($user_agent,$browser) !== false) { 
echo "The website is not supported on this browser";
}
```

Or using preg_match

```
 <?php

    $user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
if(preg_match('/MSIE/i',$user_agent))
    {
        echo "The website is not supported on this browser";
    }
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

This may be obvious but have you tried looking at Modernizr? (http://modernizr.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter has a built-in library :

```
$this->load->library('user_agent');

if($this->agent->is_browser('Internet Explorer') && $this->agent->version() < 9) // Internet explorer older than i.e 9
{
    redirect("forbidden"); //Redirect, load view, echo, whatever you want to do
}
```